# adding a word at the end of first line in etc/hosts using shell

Tags: shell

Pl. see the following input , i want to add a word(1234456) at the end of first line in /etc/hosts .

can any one suggest to me how this can be done?

ex: input

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

**expected output**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 1234456
::1         localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Comment: `sed '1s/$/ 1234456/' /etc/hosts` should do it. but I'm sure similar questions have been asked here before.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk 'NR==1{$0=$0 FS "1234456"}1' /etc/hosts
```

OR  using sed

```
sed ' 1 s/.*/& 1234456/' /etc/hosts
```

OR if line number is not sure.

```
awk '/^127.0.0.1/ {$0=$0 FS "1234456"}1' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks to all. The other thing i want to know is, how can i pass hostname instead "1234456". i tried in the following manner but could't do it. 

sed '1s/$/ `hostname`/' /etc/hosts   

(or)

awk 'NR==1{$0=$0 FS `hostname`}1' /etc/hosts 


please advice. Heart-full thanks in advance

Comment: Double quote hostname in awk. Also if u want to make persistent changes in /etc/hosts then use sed -i